# Get Minimum bounds of 4 LatLon

Tags: latitude-longitude, extents

I have 4 Lat Lon positions. They represent a (rotated) rectangular region. But due to some calculation errors, sometimes they are not proper rectangular.

I want to convert those into (rotated) rectangular regions.
See Image for more clarification

[image]

In the above image I want the lat lon of the corners of the rectangle drawn given 4 lat lon as shown on the left side.

I tried searching but couldn't find any solution. Most of the solutions did not take care of rotated rectangle case. 
How do I solve this problem ?

Note : Are there any libraries that does this, I am using JavaScript for implementation.
Note : I don't know if my question is more related to math.

Comment: Is the rotation known or arbitrary?

Comment: rotation is arbitrary ..

Comment: See http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/pdf/calipers.pdf for smallest area bounding rectangle discussion. This can probably be greatly simplified if you only have 4 points.

Comment: Solving this problem on a spheroid with great circle routes is non-trivial. There are also many potential complications (for example, what if both pairs of opposite lines are not parallel?). Manufacturing output from poor quality input usually results in poor quality output.

Comment: Please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082711/get-minimum-bounds-of-4-latlon/28104100#28104100